# ormlite read Date as 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I need to read a sqlite databse given to me, so I cannot change the Date format (yyyy-MM-dd) in the tables.  When I try to use ormlite to generate object for me, using the following annotation:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "REVISION_DATE", dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING)
public Date revisionDate;
```

it gives me the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems with column 3 parsing date-string '2012-05-01'
      using 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'
```

is there any place I can tell ormlite I want to use "yyyy-MM-dd" as the date string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you take a look at the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) documentation about [date formats](http://ormlite.com/docs/date-formats) you will see that it mentions the [`@DatabaseField.format` field](http://ormlite.com/docs/format-field).  Here are the [javadocs for `format`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#format%28%29).  This allows you to set the `Date` format.

The following should work:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "REVISION_DATE", dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING,
      format = "yyyy-MM-dd")
public Date revisionDate;
```

Comment: I was looking at format but wasn't thinking about putting it in after dataType.  It works now! Thanks @Gray!!! (will set as accept as soon as it lets me)

Comment: Just to make sure @Yenchi, it doesn't matter where you put the `format` field as long as it is in the `@DatabaseField`.