# ORMLite insert Date with SQL

Tags: android, date-format, ormlite, sql-insert

I have set up an ORMLite database in my android project.

I have a class called RbFehler with the following field in it:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "DATUM_LA", dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING,
    format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public Date datum_la;
```

I have some logic that imports the data from a text file where the SQL-insert statements are stored. One line would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO RbFehler (KATALOGART,SYST,SUBSYST,KOMP,BAUTEIL,BEZ,PSYST,PSUBSYST,
    PKOMP,PBAUTEIL,INAKTIV,GELOESCHT,DATUM_LA)
    VALUES ('VW','4F5AB211','0600','4F5AA900','0010','Venturirohr','4F5AB211',
        '0600','4F5AA900','0000','0','0',2012-06-04 08:08:08);
```

But i always get the following error when i call:

```
dao.execute RawNoArgs(line);

java.lang.Illegal Argument Exception: Field class java.sql.Date for field
    Field Type:name=datum_la,class=RbFehler is not valid for data
    persister com.j256.ormlite.field.types.DateStringType@416ed260
```

I have also tried to add " ' " around the date in the SQL-statement but get the same error.  If I remove the date from the SQL and the class everything works fine.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I only found questions like this: [ormlite read Date as 'yyyy-MM-dd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847484/ormlite-read-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out:

Make sure that you use the right Date object in Java:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "DATUM_LA", dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING,
 format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public java.util.Date datum_la;
```

And not the `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: As an aside, I've improved the ORMLite error message here to give the _expected_ class for the data type.  That should help someone in the future.